# Dockerized Django tests only look at first $PATH location

Tags: python, django, linux, docker, django-tests

I'm running a Django test suite in a Docker container, and some of these tests use a program I've had to `apt-get install` (`wkhtmltopdf`). Now I can see that it's been installed correctly:

```sh
$ wkhtmltopdf --version
wkhtmltopdf 0.12.5
```

but for some reason the Django test can't use it. The installation location is definitely on my `$PATH` (third to last element):

```sh
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
$ find / -name wkhtmltopdf
/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

However when I run tests I get a stack trace ending in:

```sh
OSError: No wkhtmltopdf executable found: "/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf"
If this file exists please check that this process can read it. Otherwise please install wkhtmltopdf - https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/wiki/Installing-wkhtmltopdf
```

Now it's absolutely correct that there is no `/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf`, because it got installed elsewhere (`/usr/bin/`) but both those locations are on `$PATH`.

I've tried moving `/usr/bin/` to the start of `$PATH`, but I then get the error:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

presumably because it's now looking in `/usr/bin/` for `django` when it's actually in `usr/local/bin/`, which is no longer the first location on `$PATH`.

I'm not sure if the problem is a Docker one, a Django one, a testing one, or just me misunderstanding one or more things going on here.

Comment: Show us a complete workflow that reproduces the problem including all docker commands and the Dockerfile!

Comment: Do you have `apt-get install wkhtmltopdf` in the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that the project is using `pdfkit` as a wrapper for `wkhtmltopdf`, which includes setting the `wkhtmltopdf` path directly:

```py
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=settings.WKHTMLTOPDF_BIN)
```

which after a quick look at the Django settings file was set to:

```py
WKHTMLTOPDF_BIN = '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
```

Mystery solved! The fix in this case was to simply set it to the actual path desired (`/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf`).